# Как быть с зеркалами на WordPress? Почему он с ними работает некорректно?

Tags: wordpress

На зеркалах (прилинкованных доменах) не отображаются подгруженные из css шрифты (с относительными адресами). Далее, все ссылки на проекте уводят на определённый в CMS адрес-сайта, т.е. на основной.

Вычитал, что новые редакции WordPress отказались от работы с зеркалами.

Трудно в это поверить - это же регресс.

И как быть в такой ситуации, когда имеются 2 и более доменных имён на один сайт?

P.S. С WordPress работаю впервые.

Comment: настроить на виртуальных хостах замену `site-1.ru` на `site-mirror.ru` через [sub_filter](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html). На PHP можно сделать тоже самое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что вы описываете, - нормальное поведение WordPress, с самых первых версий. Он хранит в базе данных домен сайта и формирует абсолютные адреса страниц.

Вам нужно установить плагин [Multiple Domains](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-domain/). Плагин создан как раз под вашу задачу. Укажите в нём требуемые домены зеркал, и вы получите несколько сайтов на разных доменах с идентичным контентом.